# Fill matrix from list based on column name match from other list

Tags: r, list, matrix

I have some data:

```
num.list1 <- list(1,2,1,4,5)
num.list2 <- list(2,3)
num.list3 <- list(3,5,2)

num.data.list <- list(num.list1, num.list2, num.list3)

name.list1 <- list("A","B","C","D","E")
name.list2 <- list("B","C")
name.list3 <- list("A","C","E")

name.data.list <- list(name.list1, name.list2, name.list3)

all.names <- unique(unlist(name.data.list))

my.matrix <- matrix(data = NA, nrow = length(name.data.list), ncol =     length(all.names))

colnames(my.matrix) <- all.names
```

I would like to populate `my.matrix` with the values from `num.data.list` based on matching the column names of `my.matrix` with the values in `name.data.list`.

i.e. :

```
      A    B    C    D    E

1     1    2    1    4    5  

2     NA   2    3    NA   NA

3     3    NA   5   NA    2
```

Any Ideas? Thanks.

Comment: I would start with `unlist()`.  Why are you using nested lists for holding single values?

Comment: @RichardScriven: It is a simplification. In the real data each list has been extracted from a large list of multivariable data.

Comment: @mattbawn Don't think you answered Richard's question. Why `num.list.1` is a `list` rather than a standard numeric vector? Each element of it has length one; a `list` structure isn't good for this kind of object.

Comment: @nicola Yes you may be right but in my real data each list contains numeric data of differing lengths. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using matrix subsetting:

```
library(reshape2)

nm = melt(name.data.list)

my.matrix[matrix(c(nm$L1, match(nm$value, all.names)), ncol = 2)] = unlist(num.data.list)
#      A  B C  D  E
#[1,]  1  2 1  4  5
#[2,] NA  2 3 NA NA
#[3,]  3 NA 5 NA  2
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd start to give `num.data.list` and `name.data.list` the proper structure:

```
num.data.list<-lapply(num.data.list,unlist)
name.data.list<-lapply(name.data.list,unlist)
```

Then:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(my.matrix)) my.matrix[i,name.data.list[[i]]]<-num.data.list[[i]]
my.matrix
#      A  B C  D  E
#[1,]  1  2 1  4  5
#[2,] NA  2 3 NA NA
#[3,]  3 NA 5 NA  2
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is another option you can do with `Map` and `rbindlist` function, assuming that your names and data are in such an order that each element in `num.data.list` match the corresponding element in the `name.data.list`.

```
library(data.table);

rbindlist(Map(function(x, y) setNames(data.frame(x), y), 
          num.data.list, name.data.list), fill = T)
    A  B C  D  E
1:  1  2 1  4  5
2: NA  2 3 NA NA
3:  3 NA 5 NA  2
```